# TPS calculation for POD in Kubernetes with Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am new to kubernetes environment, i need to calculate POD based TPS using prometheus. Can any one guide me in this regard.

Comment: What do you mean saying transaction ?  Are talking about http requests ?

Comment: Yes right , http request for each POD

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the  `http_requests_total`  time series all have the labels  `job`  (fanout by job name) and  `instance`  (fanout by instance of the job), you might want to sum over the rate of all instances, so you get fewer output time series, but still preserve the  `job`  dimension:

```
sum by (job)(rate(http_requests_total{job="pod"}[5m]))
```

This sequence:

```
rate(http_requests_total{job="pod"}[5m])
```

returns only the per-second rate of HTTP requests as measured over the last 5 minutes, per time series in the range vector.

`rate`  should only be used with counters. It is best suited for alerting, and for graphing of slow-moving counters.

Note that when combining  `rate()`  with an aggregation operator (e.g.  `sum()`) or a function aggregating over time (any function ending in  `_over_time`), always take a  `rate()`  first, then aggregate. Otherwise  `rate()`  cannot detect counter resets when your target restarts.

If you will be interested in the total of HTTP requests you have seen in  **all**  applications, you could simply write:

```
sum(http_requests_total)
```

**EDIT:**

After digging in I have noticed that the official [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/first_steps/) uses `http_requests_total` in some examples however this metric does not seem to exist in the current stable version as http://localhost:9090/metrics does not include it.

Take a look: [http_requests_total](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/pull/1078).
Name of this metrics has been changed from `http_requests_total` to `promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total`. Try to change name of this metrics in above examples and it should work.

Please take a look: [prometheus-metrics-http-requests](https://sysdig.com/blog/prometheus-metrics/), [PromQL](https://timber.io/blog/promql-for-humans/), [prometheus-way-of-counting](https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate).

Comment: Hi MaggieO, Thanks for detailed explanation, I tried the query provided but it gave no data, i checked the list of metrics i cannot see http_requests_total, i can see kubelet_http_requests_total and many other components having http request total as metric. Can you please tell me if this metric is already enabled or i need to do some thing to enable it 
I might sound too stupid, sorry for that but i am beginner in this domain.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please take a look. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for update, you are right metric name is updated but still i did not got any result. Let me give you some more details of my scenario, I have 2 micro services deployed on separate PODs lets say MS1 is pod name having one micro service deployed and second is MS2 having second micro service deployed. I want to get http traffic handled by these 2 PODs and show that as TPS in grafana on each POD. I think i need to implement custom metrics of type gauge, on invocation of microservice it will update corresponding gauge. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you paste these proper example/information in original post?